# C# tcpclient or udp socket rate is VERY slow

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

while my network support MBS. when i tried to send 1000 packets each of 800 bytes it took around 24 seconds?
why does it take so long?
I tried also UDP but it was nor better.
are there any parameters to change? any reason for this slow rate?

the code I am using:

```
const string SERVER_IP = "10.10.10.34";
const int SERVER_PORT = 1234;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);       
    using (Stream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {

            byte[] data = new byte[800];
           DateTime start=DateTime.Now;
           for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
            {

            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            DateTime end=DateTime.Now;
            var duration = end-start;
        }
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

Edit NOTE: the size of Packet is 800 bytes (and not as posted at the begining)

Comment: Check line 43. I think that should be a 4, not a 6.

Comment: @Pete line 43 of what? If you're implying that he should show code, just say that instead..

Comment: @user271077 can you show the code you're using?

Comment: well let's guess; assuming that 800K packages will have some overheads and let's assume that these overheads will be 224K; we can assume that total package size for a single request is 1M. And assuming you are sending 1000 packages; total size of request is 1000M ~~ 1G. And it tooks 24 seconds to send packages, then your transfer rate is approximately 46M/second. Viola, I have calculated your network transmission rate.

Comment: 800KBytes * 8 * 1000 packets = 6400 Mbits / 24 secs = 267 Mbps - how fast is your network connection?

Comment: mistake I meant 800 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

First stop... [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), so much can go on over a network, best looking at a trace.

Comment: It meant to help resolve it - not everything in life is black and white, especially where networks are involved!